# Multiple files/Folder scan using VirusTotal?

Tags: malware

I want a quicker way to scan many files using VirusTotal. It's quite tiring to upload them one by one using the website.

Is there a way to do it via batch scanning?

Answer (score 2):

I found it myself using *[VirusTotal Uploader](https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/desktop-applications/)*. Scanning got super simple now via right-clicking on the file(s).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Upload an Archive

Compress your files as a zip archive and upload it.

After scanning is done, you can find detailed results under the "RELATIONS" tab.

[image: Relations tab]

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting your files from? An option for you is to use the Metascan Online API, which allows you to scan against 43 antivirus engines, similar to VirusTotal. With the API, you can essentially build your application/service to automatically send and scan.

**Disclaimer** -- I work for OPSWAT, who runs Metascan Online

Comment: The files are just stored on my local hard disk @Jeff

Comment: Can you add the url/link to your service website?

Comment: Sorry Nam, I never saw your response until now. the website is www.metascan-online.com. If the files are stored on your hard drive, you would need to grab and API key, then use the API documentation (https://www.metascan-online.com/en/public-api) to build a little script to send them over.

Answer (score 1):

I found Phrozen VirusTotal, great freeware. It works in bulk upload by creating a queue list, warns you when the upload is greater than 32mb, shows awaiting results, and tells you about the available results. Within the options, there is more functionality with it.

## The only downside is it is abandonware. There are no updates after version 3.1.

Updated:

Phrozen has released a new version of the app called WinJA.  Additional details about the app can be found [here](https://www.phrozensoft.com/2016/05/winja_the_new_unavoidable_security_software-14).